# Remove seconds from jquery script

Tags: javascript, date, widget

I'm looking for a way to remove seconds from this code, so the final result look like:
"11 december 2013", or what is the computer time format.
i did a lot of research, but nothing to solve my problem.
Thank you!

```
   <div class="date">

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write ('<p>  <span id="date-time">', new Date().toLocaleString(), '<\/span><\/p>')
if (document.getElementById) onload = function () {
    setInterval ("document.getElementById ('date-time').firstChild.data = new Date().toLocaleString()", 50)
}
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no such format provider in javascript, you can use jquery plugins or javascript native methods

Comment: do you want to remove only the seconds do you want to remove the time part

Comment: i want to remove the time part... sorry my mistake (so i can only display the date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, javascript doesn't have full month names so you have to do something like this.

**Updated** To support multiple locales you need to enter each locale you want to support manually. Code now includes english and french.

```
//get locale string from browser (Default to en-US)
var l_lang;
  if (navigator.userLanguage) // Explorer
    l_lang = navigator.userLanguage;
  else if (navigator.language) // other browsers
    l_lang = navigator.language;
  else //default (change if yours is different)
    l_lang = "en-US"; 

var now = new Date();
var montNames = [];
//english month names
monthNames['en-US'] = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

//french month names 
monthNames['fr'] = ['janvier', 'février', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin', 'juillet', 'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'décembre'];

var dateText = now.getDate()+" "+monthNames[l_lang][now.getMonth()]+" "+now.getFullYear();
```

dateText would = "11 December 2013"

Comment: I know this method, but that means i can only display months in english, not in user machine format.

Comment: you have to build your own table of languages if you want to do it in multiple languages. I updated the answer with an example...